# How to pass imageview in android in same activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

- I rarely worked on image views in android. I want to display image view after some interval every time as I want to display ads on it from server. I want to pass Image view in a function  as image view. But I don't know how to pass image view from oncreate as I worked on adapter class and where integer array of drawable images does the work properly.
- please suggest me how to pass image view as I tried to pass and tried lot of conversions but failed.
- MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // here i want to take image and pass it on via loadphoto


        loadPhoto(R.drawable.ic_launcher, 400, 100);
    }


    private void loadPhoto(ImageView imageView, int width, int height) {

        ImageView tempImageView = imageView;


        AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
        ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
        image.setImageDrawable(tempImageView.getDrawable());
        imageDialog.setView(layout);
        imageDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });


        imageDialog.create();
        imageDialog.show();     
    }

}
```

actvity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_fullimage_placename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFF" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

- Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Display image view after some interval every time as I want to display ads on it from server
>   It means you should use (need) a Timer task (for simple) or a schedule thread to make it runnable.
>   in `new Runnable() {
>   // Your work here:
>   // Load the image
>   }`

Also **notice** : update the image is excuted on UI thread.
Oh sorry, may be too far with your question.

1. If you already had your images (in your drawable/ in raw/ folder), i suggest you parse an interger, for example `loadPhoto(Integer imageSourceID, Context mContext)` and load it, using getResource()
2. If you get it from server (download), then asynctask would be a good choice. Prepare your UI in onPreExcute, do your work in onDoinBackground() and update in the onPostExcute()

I hope these will help you
 4.

Comment: ` loadPhoto(R.drawable.ic_launcher, 400, 100);` but in your function, you use 
`ImageView tempImageView = imageView;
ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.fullimage);`
I think you got trouble here because, when you **parser the source id, you should use the context.getResource() or context.getDrawable() to fetch it**